# C++, always running processes or invoked executable files?

Tags: c++, process

I'm working on a project made of some separate processes (services). Some services are called every second, some other every minute and some services may not be called after days. (and there are some services that are called randomly and there is no exact information about their call times).

I have two approaches to develop the project. To make services always running processes using interprocess messaging, or to write separate C++ programs and run executable files when I need them.

I have two questions that I couldn't find a suitable answer to.

1. Is there any way I could calculate an approximated threshold that can help me answer to 'when to use which way'?
2. How much faster is always running processes? (I mean compared with process of initializing and running executable files in OS)

**Edit 1:** As mentioned in comments and Mats Petersson's answer, answer to my questions is heavily related to environment. Then I explain more about these conditions.
OS: CentOS 6.3
services are small (smaller that 1000 line codes normally) and use no additional resources (such as database)

Comment: This depends heavily on the OS you are running

Comment: What are your non-functional requirements?

Comment: non-functional requirements? What that means?

Comment: I have added some information in question

Comment: @JalalJaberi I mean, what are you trying to achive chosing one solution over another? Performance requirements? If you are calling the services rarely then what solution you chose should not matter much with regards to performance. Simplest solution would be a network socket or Boost interprocess.

Comment: @IngeHenriksen Thank you, I am concerned about performance. But not for all services. Answer to my first question determine for which services I must use always running processes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anyone can answer your direct two questions, as it depends on many factors, such as "what OS", "what secondary storage", "how large an application is", "what your application does" (loading up the contents of a database with a million entries takes much longer than `int x = 73;` as the whole initialization outside main).

There is overhead with both approaches, and assuming there isn't enough memory to hold EVERYTHING in RAM at all times (and modern OS's will try to make use of the RAM as disk-cache or for other caching, rather than keep old crusty application code that doesn't run, so eventually your application code will be swapped out if it's not being run), you are going to have approximately the same disk I/O amount for both solutions.

For me, "having memory available" trumps other things, so executing a process when itäs needed is better than leaving it running in the expectation that in some time, it will need to be reused. The only exceptions are if the executable takes a long time to start (in other words, it's large and has a complex starting procedure) AND it's being run fairly frequently (at the very least several times per minute). Or you have high real-time requirements, so the extra delay of starting the process is significantly worse than "we're holding it in memory" penalty (but bear in mind that holding it in memory isn't REALLY holding it in memory, since the content will be swapped out to disk anyway, if it isn't being used).

Starting a process that was recently run is typically done from cache, so it's less of an issue. Also, if the application uses shared libraries (.so, .dll or .dynlib depending on OS) that are genuinely shared, then it will normally shorten the load time if that shared library is in memory already.

Both Linux and Windows (and I expect OS X) are optimised to load a program much faster the second time it executes in short succession - because it caches things, etc. So for the frequent calling of the executable, this will definitely work in your favour.

I would start by "execute every time", and if you find that this is causing a problem, redesign the programs to stay around.

Comment: Then, if a service makes of only a simple small function, and will be invoked several times in a minute, is it reasonable to user first way? (always running process)

Comment: In that case, why can't it be part of the main process in the first place, if it's that simple? Sounds like you need a programming language, rather than a "service".

Comment: It's about architecture. Main application should be simple and free of other services, because is always running process and other services may not be. There is very large number of services but each of them is small itself.